# App not searchable on google marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am not able to find my app on google marketplace. It has been published in the chrome webstore and can be found if searched from the marketplace in admin console, but can't find it by going to following link and search it. Appreciate any help in this regard.

https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace

Answer (score 0):

At this point Apps Marketplace apps are not searchable from the top level. You can get the link to your app in the CWS using the share link on the top right.

Your app should also be available via Google.com search.

Comment: I have published my app 2 weeks back, but it is still not searchable from any where, google.com or google apps marketplace...

Comment: What is the name of your application or ID?

Comment: Now its up in google, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-slate/ccnijgcacpbjachbddmjjinnkidkpaob?hl=en
Thanks

Comment: Hi Arun Nagrajan, can you please take a look at this question,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060961/google-apps-marketplace-sdk-invalid-credentials-missing-or-invalid-oauth-token
It looks like a bug on Google apps marketplace and no new apps can be published on to market place because of this issue... Thanks...