# Google Apps Marketplace SDK Invalid credentials (missing or invalid oAuth token)

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to publish an application in Google Apps Marketplace. To publish I need to upload the icons while I am trying to click the select button it is showing the error Invalid credentials (missing or invalid oAuth token)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to me as well, so I tried testing it with different users on different environments and browsers, all with the same result. I believe this is a Google infrastructure problem, not anything you are doing wrong.

Perhaps one day someone at Google might realize there's a problem and it will mysteriously begin to work again. Hard to tell, since they refuse to offer any reasonable support.

If perhaps anyone from Google happens across this thread, pushing the select button opens a modal and my javascript console contains the following error (before several other errors):

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://docs.google.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://code.google.com').

Comment: There's another possibly-relevant error, that the docs.google.com page is presenting an invalid `x-frame-options` header.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091971/google-apps-marketplace-invalid-credentials-missing-or-invalid-oauth-token/22151811#22151811

Google guy claims they fixed it, but it's still broke for me

Comment: Google guy in other thread now says the fix will be out "in a few days"